# Scroll Spy Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a header on the top and 3 columns below. There is a menu on the left column, a text container in the middle column and another right column.

When the page scroll up, the menu turns to fixed position, that works.

Problem: While the page scroll up, each menu will be highlight (Scroll Spy), but only the last menu is highlight.

Please help!

Sample in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vx1r2ed3/)

JS

```
$(function () {
    $(window).on('scroll', function (event) {
    var scrollValue = $(window).scrollTop();      
    if (scrollValue > 100) {
      $('#spy').addClass('affix');

      var elemts = $('.scroll-section');
      elemts.each(function(index) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id)
        var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id + '"]');
     navElem.addClass('active').parent().siblings().children().removeClass( 'active' );
      })
      } 
    else{
        $('#spy').removeClass('affix');
      }

    });          
});
```

CSS

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#spy {
  position: fixed;
}
.right-side {
  background: gray;
  height: 120px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div  id="spy">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scroll1">First Section</a>             </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scroll2">Second Section</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scroll3">Third Section</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scroll4">Fourth Section</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-7">
  <div class="scroll-section" id="scroll1">
    <h2>First Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-section" id="scroll2">
    <h2>Second Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-section" id="scroll3">
    <h2>Third Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-section" id="scroll4">
    <h2>Fourth Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="right-side">

  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking to see if the top of each section has passed the top of the window. Add this if statement around the adding/removing of the active class:

```
if ( scrollValue > $(el).offset().top  ){
   var id = $(el).attr('id');
   var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id + '"]');
   navElem.addClass('active').parent().siblings().children().removeClass( 'active' );
}
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Revised Demo**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/tmfbzegh/)

```js
$(function () {
        $(window).on('scroll', function (event) {
            var scrollValue = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scrollValue > 100) {
              $('#spy').addClass('affix');

              var els = $('.scroll-section');
              els.each(function(index, el) {
                if ( scrollValue > $(el).offset().top  ){
                  var id = $(el).attr('id');
                  var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id + '"]');
                  navElem.addClass('active').parent().siblings().children().removeClass( 'active' );
                }
              });
            } else {
              $('#spy').removeClass('affix');
            }
        });          
    });
```

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#spy {
  position: fixed;
}
.right-side {
  background: gray;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div  id="spy">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scroll1">First Section</a>             </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scroll2">Second Section</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scroll3">Third Section</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#scroll4">Fourth Section</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-7">
  <div class="scroll-section" id="scroll1">
    <h2>First Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-section" id="scroll2">
    <h2>Second Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-section" id="scroll3">
    <h2>Third Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-section" id="scroll4">
    <h2>Fourth Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="right-side">
  
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```